# A-Frame VR: Difference between cursor and raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I am currently creating a WebVR experience where the user has the ability to interact with the environment by 'clicking' entities as a form of interaction. What is the difference between utilizing the cursor ***fuse*** attribute and the ***raycaster***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the master branch / upcoming 0.3.0, I decoupled the logic to be a bit cleaner. The raycaster component handles purely the raycaster, and the cursor component *depends* on the raycaster and adds events/states to act like a cursor. The cursor is a specialized implementation using the raycaster.

If we want to customize the cursor's raycaster, we'll actually just customize the raycaster component itself.

https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/cursor.html
https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/raycaster.html